# Maven Dependencies for JBoss 7.1 EJB Client

Tags: maven, client, ejb, jboss7.x

I wanted to implement an EJB client for JBoss 7.1 following this tutorial
http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1177#comments which is based on the JBoss tutorial:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

I already tried the troubleshooting tips there, but still I get an exception:
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial

Did anyone else encounter this type of problem and knows which jars (or better Maven dependencies) are needed on the classpath?

Best regards,
Helge

Comment: Please post a more complete stacktrace. Or at what point in your code it throws the exception.

Answer (score 6):

Have you referred to the ejb-remote quick start ? https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/master/ejb-remote

That quick start contains the two Maven projects that are referenced in the jboss.org doc and have all the required dependencies.